# batch if statment return same result in any case

Tags: batch-file

in C:\Easy_ERROR there is only 3 files. when only in 1 file you can find the string 'alexm'

```
@echo off
@break off
@color 0a
@cls

FOR %%a IN (C:\Easy_ERROR\EIM*.txt) DO (
find /c /i "ALEXM" C:\Easy_ERROR\%%~nxa 
    IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO FOUND
    )
)

pause
exit
```

when you run it, the statement:

```
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO FOUND
```

always writing me "FOUND" for all 3 files!

its only an exemple for something else that im trying to do. but the same case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are expanded at load time. Your entire FOR construct is loaded as 1 line... regardless of how many lines it contains. So the value for %errorlevel% is NOT the run time value that you are expecting. Replace this line

```
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO FOUND
```

with this

```
IF not errorlevel 1 ECHO FOUND
```

See IF /?

Note that this specifies a true condition if errorlevel is NOT equal to or greater than 1. So this would not work if a negative value was returned, as it too is less than 1.